# How to start and kill a .net dll from java?

Tags: java, .net, azure, dll, opc-ua

I'm working on a project which aims to publish opc ua data to microsoft azure. As of now the opc publisher seems to publish data even while the opc ua server is disconnected. It simply publishes the last known value. This is not what we want. Also part of the project is an automatic discovery of new opc ua servers in the network. To achieve this I wrote a java program which starts an opc publisher instance if a new opc ua server is discovered. At first I had it only update the publishednodes.json of one publisher but this doesn't seem to work reliably.

OPC Publisher is a .NET application can be built as dll in visual studio 2017.

The problem is: My tool is supposed to kill the publisher process if the opc ua server disconnects. It does kill the java process but the opc publisher just won't stop.

---

I tried running the publisher through processbuilder and destroy the process using p.destroy() which yielded no result whatsoever.
I also tried to taskkill the process using the pid of a jar I created to house the publisher.

---

This is how I start the opc publisher:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"publisher\" && " + publisherString);
    pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = pb.start();
```

(publisherString is something along the line "dotnet opcpublisher.dll options")

This works really nice.

First try to kill the process was `p.destroy();` ...which doesn't work at all.

---

Second try is to have the main program call a secondary jar which starts the publisher:

```
ProcessBuilder publisher = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "java", "-jar", "StartPublisher.jar", options);
    publisher.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = publisher.start();
```

I then get the pid of that jar through JNA `int pid = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcessId();` and kill it later using taskkill as a second process:

```
ProcessBuilder terminator = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "taskkill /PID " + pid + " /T /F");
    terminator.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process t = terminator.start();
```

This does kill the cmd window and the java process but, as mentioned above, it does not kill the dotnet process.

---

I'm all out of ideas how to solve this problem. Is it even possible? Or do I need any additional libraries? I would be really happy if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, it requires you to know the executable name of the dotnet process. But if you do, you can kill it! :)

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList<String> pids = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        String EXECUTIBLE_TO_KILL = "MicrosoftEdge.exe";
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("tasklist.exe");
        Process p = pb.start();


        InputStream stdout = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
        while (br.ready() || p.isAlive()) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String lineNormalized = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " "); //remove multiple whitespaces.
            String[] table = lineNormalized.split(" ");
            if(table[0].equals(EXECUTIBLE_TO_KILL)){
                pids.add(table[1]); //Get pid from tasklist and add it to list to kill.
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    if(pids.size() > 0) { // If the executible is in the list. Kill it
        String cmd = "taskkill.exe /F";
        for (String pid : pids) {
            cmd = cmd + " /pid "+pid;
        }
        System.out.println(cmd);
        try{
            //Attempt to kill process.
            //ProcessBuilder will not work here.
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).waitFor();
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }


}
```